# MS SQL server: display blank for a zero-valued or NULL-valued integer field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am able to use  this:

```
select COALESCE(my_integer_field, '') from my_table
```

to display zeros for `NULL` values. How can I not to display anything (no zeros) for `NULL` or zero values, without resorting to stored procedures?

Comment: "resorting to stored procedures"??? Not sure why you feel that way. Honestly you should strive to make each every query be in a stored procedure. Honestly I don't see how a proc would help you here anyway. When you have an integer column and you try to use '' it will perform an implicit conversion. And the implicit conversion of an empty string to an int results in 0. The only way you can accomplish what you want is to cast/convert your column to a character datatype so you have an empty string. I would suggest this type of thing belongs in the front end, not in sql.

Comment: Sean, thanks for your chiming in. In my case, I just wanted to solve this without using stored procedures. I am not saying stored procedure is a bad solution.

Comment: I guess my main point still is that you should be striving to make everything a stored procedure. Trying to avoid them is completely backwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It looks like a job for presentation layer not DB.**

Anyway you could use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN my_integer_field = 0 OR my_integer_field IS NULL THEN ''
       ELSE  CAST(my_integer_field AS VARCHAR(10))
       END
FROM my_table;
```

or using `IIF` (SQL Server 2012+):

```
SELECT IIF(my_integer_field = 0 OR my_integer_field IS NULL, 
           '',
           CAST(my_integer_field AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM my_table;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RBYTEB48622)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that `blank` (empty string `''`) will change the datatype of `INT` to string.

---

Or even shorter:

```
SELECT *,COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(my_integer_field AS VARCHAR(10)) ,'0'), '') AS result
FROM my_table;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/RNA78514)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════╦════════╗
║ my_integer_field ║ result ║
╠══════════════════╬════════╣
║ NULL             ║        ║
║ 0                ║        ║
║ 1                ║      1 ║
║ 2                ║      2 ║
╚══════════════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your through and crystal-clear answer!